# flutter app runs on Android simulator but not iOS simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I am running a flutter app on the Android simulator successfully but when I run it on the iOS simulator the app opens to a white screen then crashes.

I have done all of the following about 10 times each.

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
sudo xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch
sudo xcodebuild -license

flutter update

flutter clean
xcode clean build folder
flutter build ios
flutter run
Remove the Pods folder and Podfile.lock files.
cd ios
pod deintegrate
cd ..
flutter clean
flutter build ios

Xcode 12.5.1
```

I also made sure Xcode Signing & Capabilities were set. I also stopped and removed all antivirus software.

It doesn't work by running debug and running via terminal ( `flutter run --enable-software-rendering`  ) doesn't show any errors.

UPDATE:

Deleted the iOS folder and tried to run flutter create and now getting.

```
"No option specified for the output directory"
```

flutter create doesn't work.

Got the above flutter create working and now the app won't install on the Android device at all, where as it was working before flutter create was run (suggested below). Added memory and wiped Android simulator and still won't install on Android saying not enough memory. Deleting the ios folder and running "flutter create" was a disaster.

Rolling back to original code. Still stuck on not installing on iOS. It has to be something with Xcode.

Comment: Then your last option is delete iOS folder and generate it again
make sure you have backup for IOS folder.

Comment: Not sure how to generate it again? Newbie to Flutter and Dart.

Comment: go to the root folder of the project and run flutter create .

Comment: This suggestion is a very bad idea. The iphone app still doesn't work and now Android doesn't work either, where as it did before. Now Android says insufficient memory to install apk on the Android simulator. I wiped the simulator and 5x all memory on the AVD manager and still won't install.